# Gatling trying to pull the latest version from mvn central

Tags: scala-gatling

We have a scala project and have integrated gatling to run some tests..
I am getting below  error when I run the simulation

We do not have access to mvn central from the project and want to disable gatling checking for latest version when it runs.. is there any configuration for that  ?

Gatling version - 3.9.3
Scala version - 2.13.1

```
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: unexpected_message(10); Unsupported UNKNOWN(72)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.checkRecordType(RecordStream.java:411)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:219)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:875)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(TlsProtocol.java:422)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(TlsClientProtocol.java:88)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:445)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at io.gatling.commons.util.LatestGatlingRelease$.$anonfun$fetchLatestReleaseFromMavenCentral$1(GatlingVersion.scala:121)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
    at io.gatling.commons.util.LatestGatlingRelease$.fetchLatestReleaseFromMavenCentral(GatlingVersion.scala:109)
    at io.gatling.commons.util.LatestGatlingRelease$.load(GatlingVersion.scala:161)
    at io.gatling.commons.util.GatlingVersion$.LatestRelease$lzycompute(GatlingVersion.scala:42)
    at io.gatling.commons.util.GatlingVersion$.LatestRelease(GatlingVersion.scala:42)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.displayVersionWarning(Runner.scala:110)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:48)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:89)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromMap(Gatling.scala:43)
    at com.concur.ngao.stresstest.StressTestApp$.delayedEndpoint$com$concur$ngao$stresstest$StressTestApp$1(StressTestApp.scala:23)
    at com.concur.ngao.stresstest.StressTestApp$delayedInit$body.apply(StressTestApp.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:921)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
    at com.concur.ngao.stresstest.StressTestApp$.main(StressTestApp.scala:8)
    at com.concur.ngao.stresstest.StressTestApp.main(StressTestApp.scala)
```

Looked from the gatling documentation.. Any pointers to switch off checking the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This stacktrace only appears in a DEBUG log. You shouldn't see it unless:

- either you've explicitly enforced DEBUG logging
- or you've failed to properly configure your logging framework, eg don't have a `logback.xml` file.